# Detect if a new window was opened in an Ember test

Tags: ember.js, phantomjs

I dont know if this is even possible but here is my issue :
I'm doing some javascript testing in my Ember.js application and at some point, I have a button/link that opens a new window to a partner website, when certain conditions are met.

Now I'm looking for a way to test that behaviour in my karma/qunit tests but I haven't the slightest idea of how to do that. Any pointer would be appreciated !

```
document.write('<div id="test-app"></div>');
App.rootElement = '#test-app';
App.setupForTesting();
App.injectTestHelpers();

module("Services");

test("Access services", function () {
  visit("/p/2/i/services").then(function () {
    click('#MyService').then(function () {
      // What should I do here ?
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: PhanjomJS added support for `window.open` I would look into that: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10151

Comment: Thx for the tip. I added some code because I dont see in the issue you're pointing, how I should implement that. If you add some suggestions, it would be great !

Answer (score 2):

My first recommendation would be to abstract the `window.open` functionality into a module, so the app just accesses a single interface when it wants to open a window.  It shouldn't care HOW the module does it, its only concern is that it calls the module's window open method with the correct parameters.

The way you confirm that it's calling the window open method with the correct parameters is by using method stubs for your tests by using something like Sinon.js (http://sinonjs.org/).  This will allow you to stub your window open method, and run assertions that it was called a certain number of times and with certain parameters.  It's a little hard to get set up the first time, but it's definitely a necessary evil to thoroughly testing your app.

Comment: That's an interesting way of fixing this issue that is did not imagined. Thanks for the tip, I'll investigate that and get back to you. How would you manage the "window.open" if this is done by a simple href?

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't want to add the attribute `target="_blank"` to your link?  From what I can tell, you're testing for the presence of a link under certain conditions, and the absence under others?

Comment: Additionally, you may want to check for the correct `href` attribute value. You don't need to test for the click--you're not testing the user :-)